# How much is the NJ Transit Rail Weekly Pass?

Tags: usa, tickets, price, nj-transit

I tried looking it up on the [NJ Transit website](http://www.njtransit.com/var/var_servlet.srv?hdnPageAction=BROADWAYFareTo) (**note**: not PATH), but there is no information about the Weekly Pass' price. I downloaded the NJ Transit app and Weekly Passes for Rail are not sold there. Does anyone know the price and site the source please?

Comment: In the NJ Transit website I found it: Weekly Passes: All weekly rail passes valued at $18 or more are valid for one-zone bus trips and may be used on any light rail line.

Comment: @MarcelP. can you please link to the info and make this an answer.

Comment: Are you visit New Jersey? I would like to highlight that there are two rail systems in NJ: NJ Transit Rail and PATH.

Comment: There isn't a single price; what line/station are you interested in?

Comment: @nikhil marcelp's info does not answer the question.

Comment: @phoog, you're right Less Pop more Fizz raises an important point that a lot of people out of state wouldn't know about. Since it wasn't clear in the original question that the OP was looking for an unlimited all access pass, I assumed that he had a particular route/line in mind.

Comment: The NJ Transit app will only show weekly passes beginning on Thursday (when they go on sale) for the week starting on the upcoming Saturday. I checked the app yesterday/Wednesday, no information, but can now find the rates today now that it's Thursday.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NJ Transit weekly passes are not unlimited systemwide passes. Rather, they offer you unlimited rides *only* between two predefined stations along a particular line (or combination of lines). In addition, they include a free transfer to lite rail lines in Newark and Hudson/Bergen counties and single-zone NJ Transit busses for last-mile connections.

Because of this, the price of a weekly pass varies wildly depending on what stations you are riding between. For example, Hazlet to NY Penn Station is a 133 dollar weekly ticket. Secaucus Junction to NY Penn, by contrast, is 38.50.

To find the fare for your particular route, on the NJ Transit Website, click the "schedules and fares" link at the top left and select the two stations in which you're interested. You'll see the price of a single ride, ten-trip, and weekly and monthly passes listed at the bottom of the page, under the train schedule.

Answer (score 3):

I found this information in the [NJ Transit Rail website](http://www.njtransit.com/ti/ti_servlet.srv?hdnPageAction=RailTicketsTo):

> Weekly Passes: All weekly rail passes valued at $18 or more are valid
>   for one-zone bus trips and may be used on any light rail line.

Comment: Light rail in this case refers to the Hudson-Bergen light rail and Newark light rail - a pair of small local tram services for North Jersey's two largest cities. A weekly pass does not cost 18 dollars.

Comment: This does not answer the question.